# Initialize before java date in DatePicker android

Tags: android

I need to initialize before java date in DatePicker , When tried this , the DatePicker gets initialized to year "1980 "

```
public void initCalendar(){
         Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
         cal.set(1900, 0, 1);   
         y = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));  
         m = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));     
         d = Integer.toString(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));       
     }
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want to initialize date from year "1900"

Comment: return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateListener,1900 ,0,1);

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int xxday = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int xxmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int xxyear = 1900;

datepicker.init(xxyear, xxmonth, xxday, null);
```

Comment: code updated ... if set to "1982" it works ..means year before "1980" doesnot work